# Using sessions in flask

Tags: flask

I want to add items in session and delete sessions in flask. Can anyone help with the code?

```
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/home')
def hello world():
    return "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import session from flask and use it

```
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/use_session')
def use_session():
    if 'item' not in session:
        session['items'] = {'item':'item2'}

return session.get('items')

@app.route('/delete_session'):
def delete_session():
    session.pop('item', None)
    return "removed item from session"
```